Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value
i have been trying to update like and disliked to primitive.ObjectID but i keep getting error like "write exception: write errors: [Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value]" or "error decoding key disliked: cannot decode document into []primitive.ObjectID" i dont even know what is wrong with my code, i think everything is right, but error keep coming up
code
func (f *ForumServiceImpl) LikedAPost(postId string, userId string) (*model.Forum, int64, error) {
    postObjectId, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(postId)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 0, err
    }

    userObjectId, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(userId)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 0, err
    }

    // Find the post
    filter := bson.M{"_id": postObjectId}

    var forum model.Forum

    err = f.forumCollection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&forum)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 0, err
    }

    // 1. Ensure that both 'liked' and 'disliked' are arrays
    ensureArrayFields := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "liked": bson.M{
                "$ifNull": []interface{}{"$liked", primitive.A{}}, // Set 'liked' to an empty array if null
            },
            "disliked": bson.M{
                "$ifNull": []interface{}{"$disliked", primitive.A{}}, // Set 'disliked' to an empty array if null
            },
        },
    }

    // Apply the update to ensure 'liked' and 'disliked' are arrays
    _, err = f.forumCollection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, ensureArrayFields)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 0, err
    }

    // 2. Perform the $addToSet for 'liked' and $pull for 'disliked'
    update := bson.M{
        "$addToSet": bson.M{"liked": userObjectId},    // Add userId to 'liked' array
        "$pull":     bson.M{"disliked": userObjectId}, // Remove userId from 'disliked' array
    }

    result, err := f.forumCollection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 0, err
    }

    // Retrieve the updated post
    err = f.forumCollection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&forum)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 0, err
    }

    return &forum, result.ModifiedCount, nil
}

the model
type Forum struct {
    Id        primitive.ObjectID `form:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty" swaggerignore:"true"`
    Name      string             `form:"name" bson:"name" binding:"required"`
    Title     string             `form:"title" bson:"title" binding:"required"`
    Createdby primitive.ObjectID `form:"createdby" bson:"createdby" swaggerignore:"true"`
    // @swagger.property (type: array, items: &swagger.Schema{type: string, or: &swagger.Schema{type: file}})
    Images      []string                `form:"images" bson:"images" swaggerignore:"true"`
    File        []*multipart.FileHeader `form:"file" bson:"file" binding:"required"`
    Description string                  `form:"description" bson:"description" binding:"required"`
    QuoteData   string                  `form:"quoteData" bson:"quoteData,omitempty" swaggerignore:"true"`
    Quote       bool                    `form:"quote" bson:"quote" default:"false"`
    Private     bool                    `form:"private" bson:"private"  default:"false" example:"false"`
    Category    string                  `form:"category" bson:"category,omitempty"`
    SubCategory string                  `form:"subcategory" bson:"subcategory,omitempty"`
    Liked       []primitive.ObjectID    `form:"liked" bson:"liked" default:"[]"`
    Disliked    []primitive.ObjectID    `form:"disliked" bson:"disliked" default:"[]"`
    SecretCode  string                  `form:"secretCode"  bson:"secretCode"`
    Hashtag     []string                `form:"hashtag" bson:"hashtag"`
    Incognito   bool                    `form:"incognito" bson:"incognito" default:"true" example:"true"`
    Fellowing   []string                `form:"fellowing" bson:"fellowing"`
    Views       string                  `form:"views" bson:"views,omitempty" swaggerignore:"true"`
    Pool        bool                    `form:"pool" default:"false" bson:"pool"`
    CreateAt    time.Time               `form:"createAt" gorm:"autoCreateTime" bson:"createAt" swaggerignore:"true"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time               `form:"updatedAt" gorm:"autoUpdateTime" bson:"updatedAt" swaggerignore:"true"`
}


If you are referencing the document's fields in the update part like with "$ifNull", you need to use update with an aggregation pipeline. And add some example docs for each update operation.

@aneroid can you give a working sample code

Plenty of examples in the official docs: Updates with Aggregation Pipeline. You'll need to convert that to Go.
